# How to use aws athena using nodejs?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

- Athena is analytics service for retrieving data from s3 using sql query.
- I have queried data in s3 using t aws console
- Need access to aws athena using nodejs code

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) SO is **not a Tutorial or Library Finding service**

Comment: I cant speak for NodeJS but in Python there is a module called Pyhive, and for a generic JDBC connection you have to use the Hive JDBC driver which is available from AWS, and requires some configuration.

Answer (score 4):

I am using athena like following way in my nodejs project :

> download JDBC driver from [AWS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/connect-with-jdbc.html).
>   Create a connector.js file.
>   npm install jdbc [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jdbc).
>   Paste followings:

```js
var JDBC = require('jdbc');
var jinst = require('jdbc/lib/jinst');
 
if (!jinst.isJvmCreated()) {
  jinst.addOption("-Xrs");
  jinst.setupClasspath(['./AthenaJDBC41-*.jar']);
}
 
var config = {
  // Required 
  url: 'jdbc:awsathena://athena.*.amazonaws.com:443',
   // Optional 
  drivername: 'com.amazonaws.athena.jdbc.AthenaDriver',
  minpoolsize: 10,
  maxpoolsize: 100,
  properties: {
                s3_staging_dir: 's3://aws-athena-query-results-*/',
                log_path: '/logs/athenajdbc.log',
                user: 'access_key',
                password: 'secret_key'
   }
};
 
 
var hsqldb = new JDBC(config);
 
hsqldb.initialize(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

Comment: were you able to get the Execution ID after running the query?

Answer (score 4):

Just use the `Athena` Service on the JS SDK.

[Athena JS Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Athena.html)

[AWS JS SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/)

Comment: You might want to check this out cc @flair

Comment: @CpILL did you check out the links? What didn't you understand?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the athena-express module from [here](https://github.com/ghdna/athena-express), as documented by AWS [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/using-athena-express-to-simplify-sql-queries-on-amazon-athena/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use aws-sdk and athena-express dependencies,

There's a full working tutorial in this video I made:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aBf5Qo9GZ1Yac

Comment: When linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam. Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy. Please add a disclosure to *all* your answers where you've linked to your own youtube videos.

Comment: Is there any sample disclosure format? Little bit confused about it.

Comment: The disclosure doesn't need to be particularly formal. You just need to make it very clear in the answer itself that you're affiliated with the linked content. I've edited this answer to demonstrate how that can be done. Hope that clears it up.

Comment: Ok. Got it now. Thanks for help here.

Answer (score 0):

This is code about node js with Athena connection....

```
const AthenaExpress = require("athena-express");
const aws = require("aws-sdk");

const awsCredentials = {
  region: "us-east-1",
  accessKeyId: "xxxxx", // Modified key name
  secretAccessKey: "xxxxxxxxx", // Modified key name
};

aws.config.update(awsCredentials);

const athenaExpressConfig = {
  aws: aws,
  s3: "s3://xyz/abc/",
  getStats: true,
};

const athenaExpress = new AthenaExpress(athenaExpressConfig);

(async () => {
 
  let myQuery = {
    sql: "SELECT id, name, address FROM dummydata1ealogs LIMIT 3",
    db: "database",
  };
 
  try {
    let results = await athenaExpress.query(myQuery);
    console.log(results);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }`enter code here`
})();
```